# Rails and MongoID webapp can't save data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redis, mongoid, sidekiq

I have a ruby on rails webapp hosted at digitalocean which stores its data on a mongo db through mongoID.

I'm importing some data through a common API on a sidekiq worker but then I try to create an object like:

```
array_of_consumptions = API.consumptions(id)

array_of_consumptions.each do |d|
    user.array_of_consumptions << d
end
```

I can save this data on development locally, but it has random behaviours on production. For example, if I import 1000 consumptions my web app will probably save only 20 and there are no logs reporting problems.

I thought that this problem was related to sidekiq (even working ok locally) so I switched it to another one like resque but the problem remained. I check the validation of the saved objects and they are all valid after "saved".

Could this be related to transactions or problems on connections to mongodb?

Comment: by any chance... is your mongodb 32bit ?

Comment: 64bits. But, Nevermind... I found out that I had a bug within another part of the code. It's solved now.

Comment: and btw, thank you for your interest with this problem!